# Why there is no popitem for set in python?

Tags: python

Set is unordered and unindexed. Thus, there is no concept of last entered element. Thus, there is no popitem.  Is this the reasoning for no popitem in set?

If this is valid reasoning then why dictionary has popitem. dictionary is also unordered like Set.

Comment: Probably... There is an [`OrderedSet` recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/) linked from [official Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) and it defines a `pop` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding method for sets is `pop()`:

> #### `pop()`
>
> Remove and return an arbitrary element from the set. Raises `KeyError` if the set is empty.

Prior to Python 3.7 dicts were unordered and `popitem()` returned an arbitrary key-value pair. It's only since 3.7 that dicts have been ordered and `popitem()` defined to return items in LIFO order.

It's called `popitem()` for dicts because there's already a `pop(key)` method that removes the item with the specified key.

Answer (score 0):

[Python set](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) has `pop()`, to return an *arbitrary* item. You don't know which one it turn, though.

Comment: `popitem` used to act the same way before dictionaries were made ordered.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to remove the last-entered element from a set because set is unordered in Python.

If you want an easy way to emulate an ordered set using the standard library you can use `collections.OrderedDict` instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
s = OrderedDict.fromkeys((2,5,2,6,7))
s.popitem()
```

From the example above, `s.keys()` would become:

```
odict_keys([2, 5, 6])
```